# Total value attribute for all checked boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

This jQuery code tries to total all the `value` of the `input` elements with `class = valid` that are checked. How is it done?  thx

```js
Template.checkbox.events({
  'click .valid': () => {
    $("input.valid:checked").each( function () {
      console.log(this);  //total them here 
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="checkbox">
  <div class="checkbox-container">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label class="check">
        <input class="valid" type="checkbox" name={{name}} value={{value}} checked={{checked}}>{{label}}
        <input class="count" type="checkbox" name={{name}} value={{value}} checked={{checked}}>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Well, you'll need a variable inside the click handler to act as a sum, then simply, inside the .each() function, add $(this).val() to the sum variable. At a guess. I don't know Meteor, so I couldn't say for sure, but that's the way I'd go.

Comment: [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is good for sums over loops.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var total = null;
Template.checkbox.events({
  'click .valid': () => {
    $("input.valid:checked").each( function () {
      total += parseFloat(this.value);
    })
  }
});
console.log(total);
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to create a variable outside a Template event handler in Meteor. It should be stored in a `Session` if you need it outside the scope of the event helper.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I don't know anything about meteor, so that explains my error on that, but the overall idea that a variable needs to be set up to hold the answer and the values need to be added to that variable is correct regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is good, now you just need to increment a value each loop. You can use `.map` to get all the values to an array, then `reduce` it:

```
var total = $("input.valid:checked").map( function () {
  return this.value;
}).get().reduce(function(t, number) {
    return t += parseInt(number, 10);
}, 0);
```

Comment: @SterlingArcher - I could lambda the `reduce` call - but the jQuery `each` probably shouldn't be, would mess with the `this` value

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a more meteoric way to handle this, but I despise meteor so I'll agree

Comment: @SterlingArcher - And I've never used meteor... with our combined knowledge we could use *more* jQuery!